# STUFF in SQL Server with 2 tables on primary ID

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `Contracts` and `Locations`.

- `Contracts` columns: `CTX_ID, Parent_CTX_ID, Company_name`
- `Locations` columns: `CTX_ID, State`

I'm trying to create an out put that concatenates the STATE in one column for each `Parent_CTX_ID`.

Contracts table:

```
CTX_ID | Parent_CTX_ID | Company_Name
-------+---------------+-------------
1      | 100           | ABC
2      | 100           | ABC
3      | 100           | ABC
4      | 200           | DEF
5      | 200           | DEF
6      | 200           | DEF
```

Locations table:

```
CTX_ID | State
-------+------
1      | NJ
2      | PA
3      | DE
4      | NJ
5      | TX
6      | CA
```

Output I'm trying to get:

```
CTX_ID | Parent_CTX_ID | Company_Name | State | States
-------+---------------+--------------+-------+-----------
1      | 100           | ABC          | NJ    | NJ,PA,DE
2      | 100           | ABC          | PA    | NJ,PA,DE
3      | 100           | ABC          | DE    | NJ,PA,DE
4      | 200           | DEF          | NJ    | NJ,TX,CA
5      | 200           | DEF          | TX    | NJ,TX,CA
6      | 200           | DEF          | CA    | NJ,TX,CA
```

Current code:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT 
     c.parent_ctx_id,
     STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + s.state
            FROM Locations s
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as STATES
 FROM   
     Contracts AS c
 INNER JOIN 
     Locations AS s ON s.ctx_id = c.ctx_id)
```

Current output:

```
Parent_CTX_ID | States
--------------+---------------
100           | CA,DE,NJ,PA,TX
200           | CA,DE,NJ,PA,TX
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If you're using SQL Server 2017 or later you should use `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: I've tried STRING_AGG and the code rejects as unknown so I'm assuming it is prior to 2017.

Comment: Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on your SQL Server to get the exact version number

Comment: Is 'Parent_CTX_ID' supposed to self join back to the Contracts table?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  P.CTX_ID,
  P.Parent_CTX_ID,
  P.Company_Name,
  L.State,
  (
    STUFF((SELECT
      ',' + s.state as [text()]
    FROM
      Contracts AS c
      JOIN Locations AS s ON
        s.ctx_id = c.ctx_id
    WHERE
      C.Parent_CTX_ID = P.Parent_CTX_ID
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
  ) States
FROM
  Contracts P
  LEFT JOIN Locations L ON
    L.CTX_ID = P.CTX_ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/221de5/12)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CTE for the new locations (with parent_ctx_id) and use that in your query like below:

```
;WITH NEW_LOCATIONS AS
(
    SELECT l.CTX_ID, l.[State], c.Parent_CTX_ID
    FROM @locations l
    JOIN @contracts c ON c.CTX_ID = l.CTX_ID
)
--SELECT * FROM new_locations
,cte AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT c.parent_ctx_id, 
              STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + s.state
                     FROM NEW_LOCATIONS s
                     WHERE s.Parent_CTX_ID = c.Parent_CTX_ID
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as STATES
       FROM   @contracts AS c
       GROUP BY c.Parent_CTX_ID
)
--SELECT * FROM cte
SELECT c2.CTX_ID , c.Parent_CTX_ID , Company_Name , l.[State] , States 
FROM cte c
JOIN @contracts c2 ON c.parent_ctx_id = c2.Parent_CTX_ID
JOIN @locations l ON l.CTX_ID = c2.CTX_ID
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ae5fcfec5eca3c080f825adb07f0e5b)**.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm limited in CTE creation through the program's report interface, but this absolutely worked!